# How to send data from numerous drop down lists by clicking single button?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

Got a table which stores information about pupils.

```
CREATE TABLE pupis (name TEXT, city TEXT, caretaker TEXT);
```

By opening [this web-site](http://onebuttonforallselects.rf.gd/), info from this table is showed.
There is a "Sort" button, which sorts all the pupils by their cities.
Also by clicking this button, a drop down list occurs near every pupil.
This list allows to choose a caretaker for a pupil.

This way, my question is **how to send all chosen caretakers from numerous drop down lists by clicking single button?** (UPDATE TABLE)

I am sorry I am new to PHP and right now I do not understand how to be here. I can only suggest to create arrays dynamically that consists of pupil id and its caretaker.

I've created [this web-site](http://onebuttonforallselects.rf.gd/) especially for this question and this code is how that site works:

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$link = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
    or die('' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($mysql_dbname) or die('');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM pupils';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="sort" value="Sort">
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST["sort"]))  {
    $link = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) 
        or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($mysql_dbname) or die();
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM pupils  WHERE city = "Moscow";' or die("died");
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
        echo "<h1>Moscow</h1>";
        echo "<table>\n";
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            echo "\t<tr>\n";
            foreach ($line as $col_value) {
                echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\t\t";
            }

            echo "<td><form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
                echo "<select name=\"choose_caretaker\" required>";
                    echo "<option value=\"0\">Choose a caretaker</option>";
                    echo "<option value=\"Caretaker1\">Caretaker1</option>";
                    echo "<option value=\"Caretaker2\">Caretaker2</option>";
                    echo "<option value=\"Caretaker3\">Caretaker3</option>";
                echo "</select></td>";
            echo "</form>";

            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table>\n";
    }

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM pupils  WHERE city = "London";' or die("died");
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
        echo "<h1>London</h1>";
        echo "<table>\n";
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            echo "\t<tr>\n";
            foreach ($line as $col_value) {
                echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\t\t";
            }

            echo "<td><form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
                echo "<select name=\"choose_caretaker\" required>";
                    echo "<option value=\"0\">Choose a caretaker</option>";
                    echo "<option value=\"Caretaker1\">Caretaker1</option>";
                    echo "<option value=\"Caretaker2\">Caretaker2</option>";
                    echo "<option value=\"Caretaker3\">Caretaker3</option>";
                echo "</select></td>";
            echo "</form>";

            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table>\n";
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($link);
}?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="send_to_caretakers" value="Send">
</form>

<?if (isset($_POST["send_to_caretakers"]))  {  

    $link = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) 
        or die(' ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($mysql_dbname) or die('');
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');

    echo "Sent to the caretakers";
    $temp = $_REQUEST['choose_caretaker'];
    echo $temp;
    // Have no idea how it can designed

    mysql_close($link); // Закрываем соединение
}
?>
```

Comment: I was told to add an ID field to the table and do not create forms for every select. So I am doing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To use array for "select name" e.g choose_caretaker[pupil_id]
2. add in "multiple" in select box to select mutiple
3. render your result in php. you will see your caretaker under a pupil in array format.

   ```
     echo "<td><form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
           echo "<select name=\"choose_caretaker[$link['id']]\" multiple required>";
               echo "<option value=\"0\">Choose a caretaker</option>";
               echo "<option value=\"Caretaker1\">Caretaker1</option>";
               echo "<option value=\"Caretaker2\">Caretaker2</option>";
               echo "<option value=\"Caretaker3\">Caretaker3</option>";
           echo "</select></td>";
       echo "</form>";
   ```

Comment: Thank you, Mr.
Try to do that and will post a callback.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Done it.
(but multiple is not needed here, because a pupil can have only one caretaker)